# Cassandra API equivalent of "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id IN ('...', '...', '...');"

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Assume the following data set:

```
id       age  city      phone
==       ===  ====      =====
alfred   30   london    3281283
jeff     43   sydney    2342734
joe      29   tokyo     1283881
kelly    54   new york  2394929
molly    20   london    1823881
rob      39   sydney    4928381
```

To get the following result set ..

```
id       age  phone
==       ===  =====
alfred   30   3281283
joe      29   1283881
molly    20   1823881
```

.. using SQL one would issue ..

```
SELECT id, age, phone FROM dataset WHERE id IN ('alfred', 'joe', 'molly');
```

What is the corresponding Cassandra API call that would yield the same result set in one command?

Comment: addition to jbellis answer: the client Thrift API is well explained on the Cassandra wiki page under the API section: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL (Cassandra's SQL-like query language) now supports this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE keyalias IN ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...);
```

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#Filteringrows

Answer (score 4):

you would do a multiget_slice w/ keys of alfred, joe, and molly, and SlicePredicate column_names of id, age, phone

Answer (score 2):

A Cassandra equivalent could be modelled as described below:

```
Users = { //this is a ColumnFamily
  "alfred": { //this is the key to this Row inside the CF
     "age":"30",
     "city":"london",
     "phone":"3281283"
  }, // end row
  // more rows...
}
```

where "alfred" is your (row) key and the row has three columns; age, city and phone. (Omitted the timestamp field (for simplicity) for the three columns)