# How to get a list of items when using cassandra

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra

When using a nosql type datastore like Cassandra, how would you return a result set based on a column?

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE category='blah'
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

is this something that you would store in a sql db and then pull the data from cassandra?  Or can cassandra handle this type of query? (assuming millions of rows in a db)

From what I understand, cassandra is great at key based lookups, confused if it can and should be used for getting a list of data back and paging that data also (and if it is highly performant)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445878/cassandra-api-equivalent-of-select-from-where-id-in/2448225#2448225

Answer (score 1):

You create a CF whose keys are your categories, and whose columns are the articles in that category.  Then lookup-by-category is just another lookup-by-key.  Clients like lazyboy will automate this for you.

Comment: are java based clients available that support all operations?